# Loss of Precision parsing Floats

Tags: json.net

When parsing the following JSON string the float value for the x coordinate is being changed.

```
{
 "spatialReference" : {
   "wkid" : 4326
 },
 "candidates" : [
   {
     "address" : "240000001",
     "location" : {
       "x" : -79.939219121531494,
       "y" : 40.852153506889806
     },
     "score" : 100,
     "attributes" : {

     }
   }
 ]}
```

Upon calling JObject.Parse on the preceeding xml it is transformed into

```
 {
  "spatialReference": {
    "wkid": 4326
  },
  "candidates": [
    {
      "address": "240000001",
      "location": {
        "x": -79.9392191215315,
        "y": 40.852153506889806
      },
      "score": 100,
      "attributes": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there a way of forcing the parser to treat the x/y values as strings and keep the higher precision?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you deserialize into a strongly typed object where the x and y properties are decimals then you won't lose any precision.